# Change of `solrconfig.xml` (e.g. 'defaultFieldType') with Solr Config API

Tags: solr

Is it possible to change setting of `solrconfig.xml`, e.g. the value of `defaultFieldType` in the following excerpt from `solrconfig.xml` using Solr Config API?

```
<config>
  ...
  <updateRequestProcessorChain name="add-unknown-fields-to-the-schema">
    ...
    <processor class="solr.AddSchemaFieldsUpdateProcessorFactory">
      <str name="defaultFieldType">strings</str>
    ...
    </processor>
    ...
  </updateRequestProcessorChain>
  ...
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [stated in the docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Config+API#ConfigAPI-CommandsforCustomHandlersandLocalComponents): you cannot create/edit updateRequestProcessorChain elements at all. So the short answer is: No.

But, as the doc also explains, you could add a *new* updateProcessor called yourprocessor (not a updateRequestProcessorChain) that is very similar to the one you want to modify, but already has that value you need in there. You have to be careful to properly map all xml attibutes/elements propertly to json, check the doc samples.

Then, on every update request, you can ask for this processor to be used by adding processor=yourprocessor param.